# Validate Column values while insert in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have the following example

```
create table Test (
 C1 nvarchar(50) not null,
 C2 number,
 C3 date);

insert into Test(C1,C2,C3) select (v1,v2,v3)from emp ;
```

i want to add validations not to insert null values for C1, not to insert string for C2, insert dates **only** for C3.

any idea to do that in **pl/sql**?

thanks

Comment: Oracle will already do this for you. If your bulk insert attempts to put a NULL into TEST.C1 an exception will be raised. Even if the code catches and ignores the error, as soon as an attempt is made to COMMIT the changes an exception will be raised AGAIN - and if THAT is ignored and the program exits with uncommitted changes, those changes will be rolled back by the database engine. Ditto and likewise for the other columns - but note that if you try to put a "string" value into C2 which can be successfully converted to a NUMBER, the insert will still work. Same for dates. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do anything with your table definition, Oracle will throw an error if you try to insert "wrong" data.

I have also spotted that you should use the `select` statement without parantheses:

```
insert into Test (ca, c2, c3) select v1, v2, v3 from emp;
```

*Maybe*, what you really want is to only insert those records that fit the table constraints. In that case you can use `dbms_errlog` along with the `log errors into` clause.

The records that don't fit your criterias will then be inserted in another table for further review.

See [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a6f4/2).

Comment: thank u very much, this will help.
but the main problem that i want to insert bulk data from emp table to
test table in a single insert, if one column at least violate the constraint i want to prevent the user from insert and return error
messgaes.  any help please?

Comment: Have you looked at the sql fiddle that I provided?